# How can I get output "Table created" with perl DBI

Tags: perl, dbi

There is a code I would like to get output with Perl DBI "Table created":

```
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle qw(:ora_session_modes);

$dbh=DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:", "", "", { ora_session_mode =>
      ORA_SYSDBA , RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 1 } );
$dbh->do(qq{  create table test ( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL )    } );
```

How can I get this output "Table created" from DBI?

Comment: Why output from DBI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get this answer directly from DBI. DBI does not really care about what it is executing, it just passes things to and fom the database. Only you (or the code you wrote) know that the statement you ran was a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

So if you want to print `TABLE CREATED`, or even `TABLE test CREATED`, you must check the return value as suggested by some other answers here and assemble the message yourself.

Answer (score -1):

If the Query is not executed successfully print the error message.

```
  $Local_Dbh->do($Query) or print " Unable to execute the query $Local_Dbh->errstr";
```

If the table is not created , It will return the undef or -1   otherwise return the value like

```
     Result : 0E0
```

Comment: Good solution. I feel it would be more good if we handle the error along with print statement.